# Excess whitespace/padding on right side in landscape mobile view

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

As you can see, there is extra unwanted whitespace to the right of the page.

For some reason my Android phone won't cooperate with my PC so I can't do remote debugging to see which element is causing the glitch.

I narrowed it down with trial and error, and it happens anytime there is an Event Details object on the page.

If you go to https://merkd.com/events/history on a mobile device and use it in landscape orientation, you will notice you can scroll to the right and view an extra bit of blank white space.

I imagine it's an issue with some padding but I looked through the relevant CSS file (https://merkd.com/engine/ui/themes/lux/assets/css/style.events.css) but nothing stood out.

Is anyone able to see which element is causing this issue?

Running a Galaxy S5 with Chrome

As someone pointed out, I should add the HTML in case the link ever becomes invalid. Here is the HTML for the Event Details section:

```
<div class="middle_events">
        <div class="container gray">
            <!--<div class="history">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#">Event History</a></div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 right"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
                  </div>
               </div>-->
            <!-- <div class="recent_event">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12"><p>No upcoming events to display. <a href="#">View past events?</a></p></div>

                  </div>
               </div>-->
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="title-area" style="margin-top: 4em;">
            <h2 class="title">Featured Event</h2>
            <span class="line"></span>
            <p>We let you know which Events &amp; Petitions are most popular.</p>
        </div>
         -->
        <div class="container gr">
            <div class="highlight">
                <h1>Event Spotlight</h1>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="high_inner">
    <div class="container wht">
        <div class="row pd">
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 1em;"><a href="/events/add-filter(4,game)">Similar events</a></div>
            <div style="float: right; padding-right: 1em;"><a href="/events/4/XOK-vs-LSK-Rematch">More details</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="games_all">
            <div class="row" id="event4">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/usr/events/thumb.php?src=gtav.jpg&w=600" title="XOK vs LSK Rematch" alt="XOK vs LSK Rematch" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="games_all_inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-9 event-details-event-title">
                                <a href="/events/4/XOK-vs-LSK-Rematch">XOK vs LSK Rematch</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                                <a href="/events/4/XOK-vs-LSK-Rematch/like" class="like event-details-like-link-container">Unlike</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="my_hr">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                <p class="game_name">Call of Duty: Black Ops II</p>
                                <h3 class="datntime">July 27, 2015 <span class="normal event-details-start-time">Started at 7:26am</span></h3>
                                <div class="res">
                                    <div class="odd">Odds are locked</div>
                                    <div class="cntest center">
                                        <h4>5:2</h4>
                                        <h4>ExtraordinaryKillers : Los Santos Kings </h4>
                                        <a href="#">More details</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bet">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12 event-details-pot-container">
                                            <h3>Total Pot:<span>  <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>10,450</span></h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="event-details-bet-button-container">
                                            <button>Place your bet!</button>
                                            <!-- <p class="like_thumb">+3<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></p> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="eventLikesContainer" id="event4LikesCollapsed">
                                <a href="javascript:expandLikes('event', 4);" style="display: block; float: right; font-size: 1em; color: #006600;">
                                    4  people like this
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="eventLikesContainer eventLikesExpanded" id="event4LikesExpanded"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="right-tabs clearfix">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <div class="pro_title">
                                <div class="img_pro"><img src="/engine/ui/themes/lux/assets/images/performance.png" /></div>
                                <h1>Performance Reports</h1>
                            </div>
                            <li class=""><a aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_c">Reviews</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_b">Stats</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_a">Events</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="tab_a" class="tab-pane active">
                                <div class="row center">
                                    <div class="event-details-participant-container">
                                        <div class="player_win">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="outcome win" style="display: block;">Winner</div>
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="/usr/teams/icons/thumb.php?src=1441676463.1.jpg&w=150">
                                                <div class="details_all">
                                                    <a href="/teams/ExtraordinaryKillers">
                                                        <p>ExtraordinaryKillers</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span class="winloss win">W</span>
<span class="winloss win">W</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                <div class="vs">
    <div class="vs_1">
        <a href="/events/3/XOK-vs-LSK-Rematch">1. XOK vs LSK Rematch</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vs_2">
        <span class="winloss win">W</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vs">
    <div class="vs_1">
        <a href="/events/1/ExtraordinaryKillers-vs-LS-Kings">2. ExtraordinaryKillers vs. LS Kings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vs_2">
        <span class="winloss win">W</span>
    </div>
</div>
                                                <div class="vs_bottom">
                                                    <h2>Roster</h2>
                                                    <div class="vs_botttom_inner">
                                                        <a href="/u/Dan">1. danL</a>
<a href="/u/Dan">2. Pilot-Doofy</a>
<a href="/u/Dan">3. mardanlin</a>
<a href="/u/Dan">4. mardanlin</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="center middle_vs">
                                        <h1>V/S</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="event-details-participant-container">
                                        <div class="player_lost">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="outcome loss" style="display: block;">Loser</div>
                                                <img class="img-responsive" src="/usr/teams/icons/thumb.php?src=default.png&w=150">
                                                <div class="details_all">
                                                    <a href="/teams/LosSantosKings">
                                                        <p>Los Santos Kings</p>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span class="winloss loss">L</span>
<span class="winloss loss">L</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                <div class="vs">
    <div class="vs_1">
        <a href="/events/3/XOK-vs-LSK-Rematch">1. XOK vs LSK Rematch</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vs_2">
        <span class="winloss loss">L</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="vs">
    <div class="vs_1">
        <a href="/events/1/ExtraordinaryKillers-vs-LS-Kings">2. ExtraordinaryKillers vs. LS Kings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vs_2">
        <span class="winloss loss">L</span>
    </div>
</div>
                                                <div class="vs_bottom">
                                                    <h2>Roster</h2>
                                                    <div class="vs_botttom_inner">
                                                        <a href="/u/Ewan">1. xEwesey</a>
<a href="/u/Ewan">2. Ewesey</a>
<a href="/u/Ewan">3. Ewesey</a>
<a href="/u/Dan">4. DanLindsey</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab_b" class="tab-pane">
                                <h2 style="color: black;">Coming soon</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab_c" class="tab-pane">
                                <h2 style="color: black;">Coming soon</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- tab content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end right-tabs -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of container -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS file contents

```
.event-details-participant-container {
    width: 43%;
    min-width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.event-details-like-link-container {
    float: right; margin-right: -2em;
}

.eventLikesContainer {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 3em;
    text-align: right;
}

.eventLikesContainer a {
    display: inline !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
}

.eventLikesExpanded {
    padding: 1em 3em 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.news .highlight {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.news_inner {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d3d3d3;
}
.img_news {
    border: 4px solid gray;
}
.img_news > img {
    width: 100%;
}
.img_news > p {
    background: gray none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.news_inner span {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.update > p {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.highlight h1 {
    background: #2f9c2b none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.wht {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.pd {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.games_all {
    padding: 25px 0;
}
.high_inner a {
    padding: 0;
}
.high_inner a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container.wht a img {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.games_all_inner a {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.like {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    padding-top: 29px !important;
}
.my_hr {
    margin: 0;
}
.game_name {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.datntime {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}
.normal {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.res {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.odd {
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
.cntest {
    background: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.cntest > h4 {
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
}
.cntest > h4:first-of-type {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.cntest.center > a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    max-width:100px;
}
.bet h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.bet h3 span {
    color: #2F9C2B;
}
.high_inner button {
    background: #2f9c2b none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 11px;
}
/*
.high_inner button:hover {
    background: blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
*/
.like_thumb {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
}
.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
.right-tabs.clearfix {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.pro_title {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 -40px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 80px;
}
.img_pro {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
.img_pro img {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
}
.pro_title h1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 38px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0.3em;
    max-width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    float: right !important;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.nav-tabs > li:first-of-type {
    margin-right: 2em;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    font-family: "Asap",sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding: 0.7em 1.8em;
}
.player_win {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.player_win img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.details_all {
    float: left;
}
.details_all > a {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
.player_win p {
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.player_win span {
    background: #2f9c2b none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
.vs {
    background: #dcf4f9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.vs_1 {
    float: left;
}
.vs_1 > a {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.vs_2 {
    float: right;
}
.vs_bottom h2 {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #444444;
}
.vs_botttom_inner > a {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.vs_bottom span {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #E43E43;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.middle_vs h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.middle_vs {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 3em;
    width: 12%;
}
.player_lost {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.player_lost img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.player_lost p {
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.outcome  {
    padding: 0.35em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.winloss {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
.win {
    background: #2F9C2B !important;
}
.loss {
    background: #E43E43 !important;
}
.tie {
    background: #1B70BB;
}
.player_vs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    border-top: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.player_vs_name {
    color: #2F9C2B;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
}
.player_vs_name span {
    color: #E43E43;
    background: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.player_lost_name {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.gr {
    background: #2f9c2b none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.highlight h1 {
    background: #2f9c2b none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.event-platform-icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}

.event-platform-icon img {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
}


.event-filter-container, .event-sort-container {
    padding-top: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}
.event-sort-container {
    text-align: right;
}

.event-filter-container span, .event-sort-container span {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#event-index-game-filter-select {
    display: inline !important;
    float: none !important;
}

.event-filter-container select, .event-sort-container select {
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    background: #dcf4f9;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.event-filter-tags-container, .event-index-view-types-container {
    padding: 1em;
}
.event-filter-tag {
    float: left; padding: 4px 8px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #FFEE88; margin: 0 5px 5px 0; border: 1px solid #777777;
}
.event-filter-tag a {
    font-weight: 600; color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0.375em 0 0.35em;
    background: #ccc;
}



.event-index-view-types-container {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0.75em 0;
}

.event-index-view-type {
    padding: 0.75em 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.event-index-view-type:first-of-type {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.event-index-view-type.active, .event-index-view-type:hover {
    border-color: #009136;
}

.event-index-view-types-container .event-index-view-type img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.event-index-view-types-container .event-index-view-type span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 8px;
}


.event-index-list {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.event-index-list li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.event-index-list li:hover {
    background: #dedede;
}
.event-index-list li.active {
    background: #FFF5BD;
}
.event-index-list li:first-of-type:hover {
    background: none;
}
.event-index-list li span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}


.event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-position {
    width: 5%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-participants {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
}
.event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-game {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 23%;
}
.event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-platform {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
}
.event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-prize {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15%;
}



@media (max-width: 995px) {
    .event-filter-container, .event-sort-container {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .event-filter-container {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 995px) {
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-position {
        width: 5%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-participants {
        text-align: left;
        width: 38%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-game {
        width: 23%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-platform {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-prize {
        width: 15%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-position {
        width: 5%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-participants {
        text-align: left;
        width: 45%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-game {
        width: 28%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-platform {
        display: none;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-prize {
        width: 15%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 625px) {
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-position {
        width: 10%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-participants {
        text-align: left;
        width: 63%;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-game {
        display: none;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-platform {
        display: none;
    }
    .event-index-list li .event-index-list-item-prize {
        width: 22%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:450px) {
    .event-filter-container span {
        display: block;
    }

    .event-filter-container select {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:410px) {
    .pro_title h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .img_pro img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }


    .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .event-details-like-link-container {
        margin-right: -1em;
    }
}


@media(max-width:390px) {
    .event-details-start-time {
        display: block; width: 100%;
        padding: 0.35em 0 0 0;
    }
}
@media(max-width:380px) {
    .pro_title h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .img_pro img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }


    .nav-tabs > li > a {
        padding: 0.4em 0.75em;
    }

}

@media(max-width:380px) {
    .pro_title h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .img_pro img {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
    }


}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: sry, can't reproduce - you need to provide some details on Device and versions

Comment: I have included the original HTML and CSS in the question for the purpose of future users. I am also using an Galaxy S5 and Chrome, all OS and apps are up to date.